# Are questions about the meaning of words in historical languages off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Specifically I'm referring to the question [What does the Aztec word “calpuleque” mean?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/what-does-the-aztec-word-calpuleque-mean). Seeing this question immediately makes me think that it should be closed because it does not ask about history. On the other hand, I'm not sure where a user would ask such a question, seeing as how we don't have an Aztec stack exchange site (yet).

Should questions that ask about definitions of words from historical languages be allowed in the History stack exchange site?

Comment: Although it isn't strictly about history, the study of history requires that the student understand the subtleties of words, how they are used and what they meant at the time.  In my opinion, the question can be left open because it can be resolved with historical sources and methods, and because the effort to answer it is within the scope of historical scholarship.